Brother MFC-8950DW compatibility
Is this office printer compatible with Linux Ubuntu LTS 22.04? How can I find and specify he device URI?
Will you specify the Device URI? [Y/n] ->Y


0: https
1: http
2: ccp
3: lpd
4: socket
5: cups-brf:/
6: hp
7: beh
8: ipps
9: ipp
10: usb://Brother/MFC-8950DW?serial=E70778H2N211091
11: hpfax
12 (I): Specify IP address.
13 (A): Auto. (usb://Brother/MFC-8950DW?serial=E70778H2N211091)

select the number of destination Device URI. ->

Scanning:
nuc@nuc:~$ sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x0bda/0x0411 at 004:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0bda/0x0411 at 004:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 004:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0bda/0x5411 at 003:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x17ef/0xa360 at 003:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0bda/0x5411 at 003:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
found possible USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9, product=0x0299) at libusb:001:005
could not open USB device 0x046d/0xc326 at 001:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x17ef/0x6044 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x0aaa at 001:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.

nuc@nuc:~$ lpstat -t
Zeitplandienst läuft
keine systemvoreingestellten Ziele
Gerät für HL-2250DN-series: usb://Brother/HL-2250DN%20series?serial=F3N158648
Gerät für HL2250DN: usb:/dev/usb/lp0
Gerät für MFC-8950DW: usb://Brother/MFC-8950DW?serial=E70778H2N211091
Gerät für TOSHIBA-e-STUDIO385S: usb://TOSHIBA/e-STUDIO385S?serial=701545LM0L1FY&interface=1
Gerät für TOSHIBA_e_STUDIO385S: ipp://ET0021B771B8F8.local:631/ipp/print
Gerät für TOSHIBA_e_STUDIO385S@ET0021B771B8F8.local: ipp://ET0021B771B8F8.local:631/ipp/print
HL-2250DN-series akzeptiert Anfragen seit Fr 28 Jun 2024 10:54:23
HL2250DN akzeptiert Anfragen seit Di 28 Nov 2023 12:03:00
MFC-8950DW akzeptiert Anfragen seit Fr 28 Jun 2024 11:05:26
TOSHIBA-e-STUDIO385S akzeptiert Anfragen seit Fr 28 Jun 2024 10:45:53
TOSHIBA_e_STUDIO385S akzeptiert Anfragen seit Fr 28 Jun 2024 10:43:22
TOSHIBA_e_STUDIO385S@ET0021B771B8F8.local akzeptiert Anfragen seit Fr 28 Jun 2024 10:41:13
Drucker HL-2250DN-series druckt jetzt HL-2250DN-series-20292.  Aktiviert seit Fr 28 Jun 2024 10:54:23
    Warte darauf dass der Drucker verfügbar wird.
Drucker HL2250DN ist im Leerlauf.  Aktiviert seit Di 28 Nov 2023 12:03:00
Drucker MFC-8950DW ist im Leerlauf.  Aktiviert seit Fr 28 Jun 2024 11:05:26
Drucker TOSHIBA-e-STUDIO385S ist deaktiviert seit Fr 28 Jun 2024 10:45:53 -
    Unplugged or turned off
Drucker TOSHIBA_e_STUDIO385S ist im Leerlauf.  Aktiviert seit Fr 28 Jun 2024 10:43:22
Drucker TOSHIBA_e_STUDIO385S@ET0021B771B8F8.local ist im Leerlauf.  Aktiviert seit Fr 28 Jun 2024 10:41:13
HL-2250DN-series-20292  nuc              25600   Do 27 Jun 2024 14:17:57


Probably, but remember that printing and scanning have different requirements.
For scanning, add yourself to the scanner group with sudo adduser $USER scanner, then logoff/login (groups are set up at logon time). Th en run sane-find-scanner. ("sane" stands for Scanner Access Now Easy).
For printing,
Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to http://localhost:631.
You can detect, add, and manage printers from the Admin tab, and deal with individual printers from the Printers tab. You can set the system default printer.
From the command line,
lpstat -t
will show the total state of the printing system.

Is the USB-connection mandatory for scanning? No ethernet?

See above for sane-find-scanner's terminal output.

Can you help me further?

Brother have deb files for most of their range
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=mfc8950dw_all

Once I attached the device over USB it installed a Gerneric PCL 6/PCL XL Printer (Driver). I'm I fine with that?

I'd need some help finding the device URI (see above).
